# Dynamically check if iFrame will break?

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, break

I'm creating a website where users enter a URL and it's displayed in an iFrame, to be brief. I know a lot of websites have code to break out of iFrames (popular example, Google).

Is there any way to check, with **JavaScript or PHP** whether a given URL will break out of an iFrame?

As a side-note, I don't mind taking a website snapshot but I haven't found an existing adequate website and I can't seem to install wkhtmltoimage/pdf...but that's a different question.

Comment: I don't know if this will be useful to you, probably not, but goole has a proyect to sandbox websites clientside http://caja.appspot.com/ with this you can see any page inside the iframe. But this is very complicate and alpha-ish for now.

Comment: This looks the same as `file_get_contents()` in PHP...do you know if there's a difference? I'll check it out though, thanks!

Comment: It works, looks good! I'm using it, I'll post here if I find a better solution. The API is really simple, I recommend this...how come I never found this? Looks like Google doesn't index its own websites :)

Comment: I've been trying Caja's API and the whole system doesn't seem to work, I tried google.com and the stylesheet didn't load, nor the images. Let me know if I'm doing something wrong, I can post my code if you want.

Comment: I am not expert of cajita, so I can't help on that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as the iframe's URL is different to that of the parent (your website) the iframe's JavaScript cannot access anything in its parent.

For cross-domain iframe communication to work one might use HTML5's **PostMessage** (which has decent support as of right now) or passing params via the **URL of the iframe**.
Both of these methods require the parent (your website) to explicitly intercept the 'calls' from the iframe and do whatever...

All in all, for security reasons an iframe from an unknown source can't simply alter the parent site holding the iframe.